# How to redirect first-time visitors to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, redirect

Is it possible for me to check whether or not my landing page URL has been visited by a visitor on my site? (and in the case that it has not been visited, serve a redirect to it?)

My problem is, that I need new visitors to view my landing page as the first thing they see. This (of course) does not happen when a visitor copy/pastes a link from one of my sub-sites to someone else.

I have been searching for a bit, but have come up empty handed. Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Maintaining a database of user IPs or setting cookies could help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use Cookies in your pages to check if the user visited the landing page before or not

you can do that by two lines

the first one in your landing page

```
document.cookie = "landingPage=visited; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
```

the second line in all your page or only in default home page to check if the use visited the landing page or not

```
if(!document.cookie.includes('landingPage=visited;')) {
  window.location.href = "http://example.com/lp.html";
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification.

Your first line creates the cookie and sets the expiry, but your second line checks for that cookie **and if it exists**, redirects - correct?

If so, in my case, the redirect would need to be an 'else' in this logic, since I only want to redirect if they **do not** have the cookie, right?

Comment: @W4yp01nt thanks for reply, but I set "!" before the condition :), that's meaning that if there isn't a cookie redirect the visitor, and in landing page we will set the cookie

Comment: @W4yp01nt short answer I checked if it doesn't exist

Comment: Implementing this, I found an issue, but fixed it.

`if(!document.cookie.includes('landingPage=visited;')) {
  window.location.href = "http://example.com/lp.html";
}`

Should actually be

`if(!document.cookie.includes('landingPage')) {
  window.location.href = "http://example.com/lp.html";
}`

Since the name of the actual cookie is just "LandingPage"

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may need to add the path the cookie belongs to during creation otherwise it won't be read at another path.

`document.cookie = "landingPage=visited; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check if a visitor (IP or COOKIES or Session id) has been visited your landing page! This is possible with a few PHP lines of code. But the best SEO practices recommend do not force redirect a visitor on a page. You can propose to the visitor a CALL TO ACTION link or banner linked to your landing page.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the approach used by facebook to keep an account secured, when you try to login to your Facebook account from a totally new location, it lands you on a checkpoint page to verify that it is you!

You can log user details like browser, location and etc, and if there details exists then user is existing otherwise new!

Or use the cookie method as described in the above answers!